# Accessing controlleradvice objects from another controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've got a `@ControllerAdvice` class what I use to set user profile information all across the application. In this way, I get the user profile in every single JSP. However, I'm trying to access to that object in a `@Controller` like this with no success:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CommonControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute("PROFILE")
    public Profile populateUserProfile(HttpSession session){
        return (Profile) session.getAttribute("PROFILE");
    }
}


@Controller
public class ActivityController {

    @GetMapping("/view/activity/{id}")
    public ModelAndView getActivity(ModelAndView modelAndView, @PathVariable Integer id) {
        Profile profile = (Profile) modelAndView.getModel().get("PROFILE");
    ... ...
    }
}
```

But I only get a `NullPointerException` because the profile is null. However, I know that it is not `null` because I can use it in the related JSP.

Comment: show your controlleradvice class

Comment: At what point is the PROFILE attribute populated in the session

Comment: It's done during the log in process.

Comment: Verify that the attribute is really populated in one of the controller by manually querying  from HttpSession public ModelAndView getActivity(ModelAndView modelAndView, @PathVariable Integer id, HttpSession session) {
        Profile profile = (Profile) session.getAttribute("PROFILE");
    ... ...
    }

Comment: @ekemchitsiga I've been able to use user profile's data in the JSP files depending this controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just pass as a parameter the `@ModelAttribute` defined in the `@ControllerAdvice` class, instead of trying to obtain it from the `ModelAndView`.

```
@Controller
public class ActivityController{

   @GetMapping("/view/activity/{id}")
   public ModelAndView getActivity (
       ModelAndView modelAndView,
       @ModelAttribute Profile profile,
       @PathVariable Integer id) {
            //Profile object is well populated
            //However I don't understand why this model is empty
          ModelMap model = modelAndView.getModelMap();
          ...
   }
}
```

It solved my problem, and I am happy with the solution, nevertheless, I expected to be able to access to this information directly in the `ModelMap`, and it is empty. I would like to know why.